# How can I tell whether SvelteKit's "load" function is running on the server vs. client?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to do API calls in a SvelteKit page from the [load](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#loading) function, but I don't want to proxy these calls with local endpoints because I want to keep the web server as light as possible.

What I want to do specifically is, when the call is made from the server, the API's URL should be different than when it's called from the client (e.g. "http://localhost:1234" vs. "https://example.com:1234", respectively).

But, more generally than this, **is there a way to differentiate whether the current code is running on the server vs. the client?**

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Within the `load` function there is the option to use the `browser` flag after it's imported from `$app/environment`.

```js
<script context="module">
    import { browser } from '$app/environment'; 
    ...
    export async function load({ fetch }) {
        if (!browser) {
            // code here runs only on the server
        }
        return {
           ...
        }
    }
    ...
<script>
```

Following comes from [SvelteKit's docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-env-browser):

> browser is true or false depending on whether the app is running in
> the browser or on the server

Comment: is there anything wrong with just process.browser?

Comment: @koo5 Wouldn't that mean adding the [process](https://www.npmjs.com/package/process) dependency? Not sure if that one is an ES module.  A CJS module may not work for SvelteKit without some unnecessary workarounds ([FAQ](https://kit.svelte.dev/faq#packages)).

Comment: can i use `browser` outside of load function?

Comment: @chovy The `browser` var gets initialized and that way gets it's value outside of the `load` function. So this var's scope is surrounding that `load` function's scope. You can of course pass the var as an arg to a scope even more outside to a custom function to use it's value in the scope of that custom function.

Answer (score 6):

Disclaimer: what I'm writing is not the real answer to the title, but it is the specific answer to the described problem.

There's a targeted [hook function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks) (`handleFetch`) that's build to address resources differently if client or server:

https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/hooks#server-hooks-handlefetch

```js
/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').HandleFetch} */
export async function handleFetch({ request, fetch }) {
    if (request.url.startsWith('https://api.yourapp.com/')) {
        // clone the original request, but change the URL
        request = new Request(
            request.url.replace('https://api.yourapp.com/', 'http://localhost:9999/'),
            request
        );
    }

    return fetch(request);
}
```